# Adjustable power resistance

Tags: transistors, power, mosfet, analog, bipolar

I have to design a circuit that must draw up to 1200 W on 12 VDC to 40 VDC, maximum 50 A, during 100 ms and be adjustable.

The first approach was to use power resistors ([LTO100](https://www.vishay.com/docs/50051/lto100.pdf)) of several values, switched in parallel.

The solution is expensive and not very adjustable. I think that transistors driven in linear or resistive modes could be a better solution.

Bipolar, MOSFET, JFET - what would be the best method (good compromise between simplicity and cost)?

I only use transistors in switching, so any help or diagram would be appreciated.

Do you have a better solution than transistors?

I will have a microcontroller so I can measure current and voltage.

I think we will like to change the value every 10 ms (not defined yet), and switch off the power after 100 ms (to avoid overheating). Then we can wait 1 minute (or more if needed) before starting again.

Comment: DC or AC? Adjustable for what reason and what range? "Best method" might mean cheapest or, at the other end of the scale the most reliable <-- what do you mean by "best"?

Comment: How fast/often do you need to switch value?

Comment: Last time I did it, I bought a two-plate stove with six power levels for each, wired them series to give higher impedance and made a chart of the 30 power/impedance options it offered. You need much lower impedance so that's unfortunately an option for you.

Comment: This is DC.
"Best method", indeed, I think it will be a good compromise between simplicity and cost. And yes, whatever the method, it must not burn.

Comment: "How fast/often do you need to switch value?"
Good question.
I think we could change the value every 10ms (not defined yet).
And switch off the power after 100ms (to avoid overheating). Then we can wait 1min (or more if needed) before starting again.

Comment: For the two-plate stove idea, it is clever. :D
But it is not really industrial for mass production.
Also, even if 1200W seems huge, the 100ms duration allows to use components on PCB.

Comment: Fix your question with all the extra information you have provided in comments please.

Comment: OK. It's done. Thanks.

Comment: 10 ms rules out relays. 12 V rules out IGBTs. 100 A DC begs for several MOSFETs in parallel with individual gate resistors.

Comment: I just checked, there won't be more than 50 A. I'll edit my question.

Comment: winny - Why gate resistors?  If you are talking about ballast resistors to even out the current sharing, those usually are in the sources.

Comment: Does the load have to be resistive? Or can you use PWM? A beefy mosfet driven with PWM and a single power resistor is the simplest solution.

Comment: @AnalogKid 1/2 That is what I was taught in school too. Fast forward a few years later and a product I developed with a MOSFET relay with two devices in parallel is put in mass production after passing the entire test battery without issues and customer returns are coming back by the pallet. Not exaggerating here, actual pallets. An emergency team was formed and we spent weeks trying to replicate and understand the behavior.

Comment: 2/2 In the worst despair, a collogue outside of the team sticks his head into the room and ask what's up. "Failing MOSFETs here" _points on schematic_ "Oh, no individual gate resistors. Have you tried that?" That was the solution! Root cause was Vgsth differences between the devices, causing oscillation during switching with high enough peak currents to destroy one device and short it. TL;DR Always use individual gate resistors when paralleling MOSFETs. Costs almost nothing.

Comment: It must be resistive, not necessarily linear. A simple PWM without filtering won't be accepted.

Comment: A resistor in series with a power MOSFET gate usually is there to dampen L-C oscillations in fast switching applications.  But another reason is to form an R-C (external R and gate capacitance) lowpass filter to reduce voltage spikes that could puncture the gate oxide layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's go for reasonably cheap. I'll go with your preferred linear implementation. So it'll be the usual MOSFET+opamp current source.

First we need current sense resistors with reasonably low tempco. A bit of search on mouser yields suitable candidates ([link](https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity-Holsworthy/SMA-A0207FTDT10R?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtlubZbdhIBIMHZ5gvv1VGt8gxk7L5%2Fduo%3D) [link](https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/Vishay-Draloric/SMM02070C1009FBP00?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtlubZbdhIBICf54C4yJnCfRzToThlEChE%3D)): MELF SMA0207 resistors, 50ppm/°C, pulse rating 10W for 100ms, cost 12 cents (by 100). I'm using the single pulse rating, because you said the device will be allowed to cool between tests. Inductance is very low which is nice, as inductive wirewound resistors can make the MOSFET oscillate.

This looks like a boardful of MELF resistors with a fan blowing on it. I suggest Arctic P12 PWM, it's pretty cheap and silent. The board could also be bolted to a heat sink with thermal vias to transfer heat to the back.

Next, a suitable MOSFET with high dissipation and wide linear SOA ; that means something rather old, not optimized for fast switching. I'll suggest  [IRFP150N](https://www.reichelt.com/fr/fr/mosfet-de-puissance-n-ch-to-247ac-100-v-42-a-irfp-150n-p41676.html?&trstct=pol_2&nbc=1): although it doesn't have a specified linear SOA, there are zillions of audio amps in the wild with these and they work just fine in linear mode.

How many in parallel? I would say 4-6 channels of these:

[image]

Let's go with 5 channels. At 12V 50A, 10A per channel, there's 5V on the resistor, it  dissipates 50W, so using 10-20 MELF resistors is fine with regards to the pulse power rating.

There are also 50ppm/°C 5W wirewound resistors which would accept this pulse power, a bit more expensive but not much. However they have a smaller surface area than lots of SMDs tied to board copper, so it'll take longer to cool them between pulses. TO-247 resistors cost more, and they'll cool down even faster. Basically, over 0.1s heat doesn't have much time to spread, so you want the largest thermal mass of resistive material in close proximity to metal or ceramic, and only the material in close proximity to the resistive film/wire will actually soak up heat. So even if it would seem crazy to use SMDs, that gives you more surface area to extract heat from the resistive film into the adjacent ceramic than a big wirewound. This means lower peak temperature, and lower tempco-related change of resistance.

At 12V 50A, 10A per channel, there's 7V on the MOSFET so it dissipates 70W. It can do this more or less continuously if the heat sink is up to the job, so no problem for a 0.1s pulse.

To operate with longer pulses, voltage on the resistors would need to be lowered, which means using a lower offset opamp.

Now, increasing voltage will increase dissipation in the MOSFETs. With 5 channels, it should work up to 200W pulsed, but I sure wouldn't push it to 40v.

One solution is to cascode the MOSFETs with similar MOSFETs, to share the dissipation. This doesn't replicate the current sense resistors and opamps, so it's much simpler than just adding more channels. You probably need two extra MOSFETs per channel, with adequate gate biasing. This will need a boosted supply (a simple charge pump) and a bunch of zener diodes.

Another solution is to insert a cheap, high-tempco wirewound resistor in the drain, which is shorted by a low-RdsON PMOS used as a switch. [KVS17](https://www.vitrohm.com/content/files/vitrohm-kvs-wirewound-power-resistor-datasheet.pdf) wirewound can take 100 Joules pulse energy, so it'll be fine. At low input voltage, the PMOS shorts the resistor, so it is not used. At high input voltage, the PMOS opens and the resistors drops voltage to lower dissipation in the current source MOSFET. This is less flexible than using cascodes, and the resistor value has to be calculated to keep enough Vds on the MOSFET so it operates, while keeping Vds low enough at high current.

Comment: Thank you very much for all these details.

If I understood the diagram correctly, the opamp allows to regulate the voltage VS to have VS = V+ , so V+ = R2*I , right?
In order to limit the power of R2, I can decrease the value of its resistance, right? (by choosing a rail-to-rail AOP in input and by decreasing my V+ voltage) 
It increases the power on the MOS, but the packages seem more adapted for this work.

I did not understand the application of the cascode configuration.
Is it not possible to simply parallel as many R1 & X1 as needed to dissipate?

Comment: Yes, it's the basic opamp+MOSFET current source (google it). Opamps dislike capacitive loads, MOSFET gate is a capacitor which adds phase lag, so it can require extra components to get good stability. But it's a classic, pretty bulletproof. Using one opamp per MOSFET means the differences in threshold voltage between MOSFETs don't matter. If you reduce the current sense resistor value too much, voltage on it willl be tiny, so you will need more expensive low offset opamps. So there's a compromise.

Comment: It's possible to not use cascodes and use one many more MOSFET current sources in parallel. You'll just need more opamps, but if they're cheap, no problem. The opamp's input common mode needs to go to 0V, but not to the positive supply, so you don't really need a rail to rail input opamp. Just "input common mode includes ground" like LM358.

Comment: Temperature sensor on heat sink is strongly advised though.

Comment: And what are the advantages compared to PSTechPaul's solution?

Comment: @AdriZ 50c dual opamp is more convenient than trimpot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I actually made something very similar a few years back. I made a 1kW variable load using a massive heatsink and an array of power MOSFETs driven linearly using small feedback resistors. Using the feedback resistor, a uController increased the gate voltage until the desired current was met. It worked perfectly well, but I burned a fair number of FETs in the process. 
My biggest mistake was not using local instrumentation amplifiers, so I had problems with offset voltages ruining my measurements. The gate response is individual and non-linear, so I had trouble coding the control loop, but largely it worked.

Of course, as many told me at the time, this is the 'wrong' way to do it. The conventional way to do it is to use an inductor with a FET, and basically make a switching power supply that dumps power into a resistor. I'd probably recommend this route.

Comment: Thank you. I thought of the switching regulator + power resistor method (and it is more in my knowledge) but it will be much more expensive.

I think there is no benefit to do switching if I need to draw all the energy.

Comment: Well, the benefit to switching is it's more reliable and safer. I must have blown 10 or so MOSFETs. But driving them linearly is totally doable and simpler (and cheaper). Just buy spares!

Answer (score 1):

It may be best to drive the MOSFETs with resistors in a source follower configuration. I purposely chose two devices with gate thresholds differing by about 1 V, and I added voltage dividers from a 4-12 volt control signal to share current equally. Trimpots could be used and adjusted as part of calibration. The power dissipation is more or less equally shared between each MOSFET and its load resistor.

Note that this is a conceptual circuit. Appropriate MOSFETs need to be chosen, and more can be added.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ3Dha.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Drive and source voltages]

[image: Load resistor currents]

Comment: Thank you for this diagram with simulation! It is very useful for me who has never driven MOS in linear mode.
If I understood correctly, the solution is similar to the one proposed by bobflux. 
Same remark, by decreasing the value of R1, I increase the power dissipated by M1?
I have trouble to identify the advantages of one or other method.